# Qt SOAP install

Tags: c++, qt, soap

I've ran into problems installing the LGPL version of the Qt SOAP component:

http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Utilities/qtsoap/

I've followed the instructions in INSTALL but can't seem to get it to build the DLL.

---

### Unpacking and installation

1. Unpacking the archive (if you have not done so already).

   On Unix and Mac OS X (in a terminal window):

   cd your-install-dir
   gunzip some-package.tar.gz
   tar xvf some-package.tar

   This creates the subdirectory some-package containing the files.

   On Windows:

   Unpack the .zip archive by right-clicking it in explorer and
   choosing "Extract All...". If your version of Windows does not
   have zip support, you can use the infozip tools available
   from www.info-zip.org.

   If you are using the infozip tools (in a command prompt window):
   cd your-install-dir
   unzip some-package.zip
2. Configuring the package.

   The configure script is called "configure" on unix/mac and
   "configure.bat" on Windows. It should be run from a command line
   after cd'ing to the package directory.

   You can choose whether you want to use the component by including
   its source code directly into your project, or build the component
   as a dynamic shared library (DLL) that is loaded into the
   application at run-time. The latter may be preferable for
   technical or licensing (LGPL) reasons. If you want to build a DLL,
   run the configure script with the argument "-library". Also see
   the note about usage below.

   (Components that are Qt plugins, e.g. styles and image formats,
   are by default built as a plugin DLL.)

   The configure script will prompt you in some cases for further
   information. Answer these questions and carefully read the license text
   before accepting the license conditions. The package cannot be used if
   you do not accept the license conditions.
3. Building the component and examples (when required).

   If a DLL is to be built, or if you would like to build the
   examples, next give the commands

   ```
   qmake
   make          [or nmake if your are using Microsoft Visual C++]
   ```

   The example program(s) can be found in the directory called
   "examples" or "example".

   Components that are Qt plugins, e.g. styles and image formats, are
   ready to be used as soon as they are built, so the rest of this
   installation instruction can be skipped.

---

I get the following error when running nmake:

C:\Qt\qtsoap-2.6-opensource>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cd buildlib\ && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe" -f Makefile

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.Debug all

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:/Qt/2009.03/qt/bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_QTSOAP_EXPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"....\2009.03\qt\include\QtCore" -I"....\2009.03\qt\include\QtNetwork" -I"....\2009.03\qt\include\QtGui" -I"....\2009.03\qt\include\QtXml" -I"....\2009.03\qt\include" -I"..\src" -I"....\2009.03\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I "debug" -I"....\2009.03\qt\mkspecs\default" -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 ..\src\qtsoap.h -o debug\moc_qtsoap.cpp

g++ -c -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_QTSOAP_EXPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -D QT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"....\2009.03\qt\include\QtCore" -I"....\2009.03\qt\include\QtNetwork" -I"....\2009.03\qt\include\QtGui" -I"....\2009.03\qt\include\QtXml" -I"....\2009.03\qt\include" -I"..\src" -I"....\2009.03\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"....\2009.03\qt\mkspecs\default" -o debug\moc_qtsoap.o debug\moc_qtsoap.cpp

g++.EXE: debug\moc_qtsoap.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.EXE: no input files
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Qt\2009.03\mingw\bin\g++.EXE' : return code '0x1'

Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\
VC\bin\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

C:\Qt\qtsoap-2.6-opensource>

Any help on solving this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `qmake` from a Qt built with MinGW.  That means you should use the `make` from MinGW, not `nmake`.

If you want to compile some Qt software with MSVC then you must use a version of Qt built with MSVC.